# Adding Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to vmware

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware, hyper-v, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using [Ubuntu 20.04 LTS](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/p/ubuntu-2004-lts/9n6svws3rx71?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) as a virtual machine along with Windows 10 on my [Lenovo Legion Y540](https://www.amazon.in/Lenovo-Legion-Windows-Graphics-81SY00C3IN/dp/B07VP6FGM8?th=1). Recently I installed [VMware Workstation Player](https://www.vmware.com/in/products/workstation-player/workstation-player-evaluation.html) and I wanted to use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with VMware Workstation Player so that I can get extra feature like shared folders etc. But I'm unable to add it to VMware. I can't find the .vmx file. The only way to add it is to download the .iso file for Ubuntu 20.04 and I don't want to that unless I've no other options.

I did some googling and found that the virtual machine files are located inside `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V` but this folder is empty for me and I also can't find option for enabling `Hyper-V` in `Control Panel->Turn Windows features on or off`.

I've added some images showing info about my Windows version, laptop details etc.
[Windows Specifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jM5bi.jpg)
[Laptop Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFe54.jpg)
[Turn Windows features on or off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E92nI.jpg)

**Please let me know in comments if you need more details.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Windows Home and that does not support Hyper-V (which is why you do not see it in Windows Features.

You should be able to install and run VMware Player (it seems that you could do this).

To install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, you need to download and install it using VMware Player. That will work fine.

I have Ubuntu 20.04 running here in VMware Workstation. I downloaded the Ubuntu ISO and then installed it. It is working just fine.

When you have downloaded the Ubuntu file (from the source you use, make a new Virtual machine in VMware Player, point the install to this file and install the machine.

Comment: I've downloaded Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from Microsoft Store. Why can't I add that?

Comment: You need to install it from VMware Player.  Save the download to a folder in your VMware folder for virtual machines, make a new machine and point the install to the downloaded file. You have to install Ubuntu to see it and make it work.

Comment: You should follow the steps described in the following article. https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2013483
Basically download Ubuntu iso, create new VM, attach iso to it and install OS. 
In case you have existing OS installation on Hyper-V you can convert it to Workstation with StarWind V2V converter. 
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-v2v-converter